# How does Journey Build make SOAP calls to Sales/Service Cloud - single record or batch?

Tags: marketing-cloud, visual-workflow, journeybuilder

Trying to determine record update and creation behavior in Sales/Service Cloud when Salesforce records are created or modified by Journey Builder activities.

Here is the scenario:

Multiple contacts are enrolled in a Journey at the same time (for example, added to a Journey Builder DE via a SQL query) and those contacts reach a Sales/Service Cloud Activity in the Journey (such as create Campaign Member record), are those requests sent via the SOAP API to Sales/Service Cloud as serial single records or a batch?

How those records are created or updated in Sales Cloud affects how Flow handles the records. If multiple records are received from Marketing Cloud as a batch, then Flow will bulkify them for record update operations.

But, if single records are created or updated from the Marketing Cloud SOAP request, then Flow will not bulkify record operations.

The question is: How does Journey Build make SOAP API requests to Sales/Service Cloud? As single record requests or batched?

Comment: I'm pretty certain the updates would be processed row-by-row and not batched by the Journey Builder activity. Journey Builder calls the activity on a row-by-row basis, so it'd be hard to imagine the activity maintaining a queueing mechanism behind the scenes to batch up the individual executions for all the users of a stack. You could test by putting a trace on the integration user's account in Sales Cloud, no?